# How to find only the exact word and not just something that contains the word being serached for in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, string, search

For a quick summary, I am writing up a little program to break down a sheet of raw data into different sections. The way they have it written down is basically:

```
#-Version
##-Category
###-Sub Category
####-Update`
```

So how do I break it up to where it only searches for the single # (Version) without triggering any of the other categories?

Thanks

Am able to break it apart into an array just not able to do what I was asking above.

Comment: Have you tried regex?

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want:

First, it splits the string by newline into an array. Then, it filters the array by a Regular Expression, which matches only when the string begins with exactly one "#" followed by a any character except a "#".

```js
<insert string>.split("\n").filter(e => e.match((/^#[^#]/));
```